# Java: Create a duplicate of an array without making it a reference

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, copy, pass-by-reference

I have written a series of matrix operations where I take a 2 dimensional float array, treat it as a matrix, and perform matrix operations on it to acquire an inverse. My problem has been that although the array I am using with the class methods isn't part of the class, every time I run the method with the array as the parameter, the array itself also becomes modified.

First I will describe how I got the inverse of my matrix and then I will show the output.

The steps to taking the inverse of a matrix are as follows:

1. Get the cofactor matrix (i.e. create a matrix of matrix minors of the original matrix and then negate every other entry. If C = Cofactor Matrix, M = Matrix of Minors, i is the current row, and j is the current column, then **C[ i ][ j ] = M[ i ][ j ]*( -1 )^( i + j )**
2. Convert the cofactor matrix to the adjugate (also known as adjoint) matrix by transposing (replacing row, column entry by its analogous column, row entry and vice versa) the cofactor matrix. If C = Cofactor Matrix, A = Adjugate Matrix, i is the current row, and j is the current column, then **A[ i ][ j ] = C[ j ][ i ]**
3. Finally, take one over determinant of the original matrix and multiply the adjugate matrix by that value. If I = Inverse Matrix, A = Adjugate Matrix and D = Determinant, then **I = (1/D)*A**
4. In order to test if you have truly acquired the Matrix Inverse of a Matrix, one can multiply the original matrix by its inverse to get the identity matrix.
   If  I = Inverse, O = Original Matrix, and id = Identity Matrix then **O*I = id**

Now I will present the code where I implement these operations. For the sake of conciseness, I will not describe how to get the Matrix of Minors or the Determinant, but the problem I have been encountering will become apparent anyways.

```
public class MatrixOperations {
    //Note: this method works fine. There are no problems.
    public float determinant(float [][] a)
    {
        float [][] temp_mat;
        float res = 0;
        //assuming a square matrix
        /*If it's a 2X2, then use the formula for a determinant of
        2X2 matrices.*/
        if(a.length == 2)
        {
            return a[0][0]*a[1][1]-a[0][1]*a[1][0];
        }
        /*Otherwise do the determinant formula recursively until your
        determinant is made up of 2X2 matrix determinants and scalar products*/
        else
        {
            temp_mat = new float[a.length-1][a.length-1];
            int placej = 0;
            int placei = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k<a.length;k++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++)
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
                    {
                        placei = i-1;

                        if(j != k)
                        {
                            if(j < k)
                            {
                                temp_mat[placei][j] = a[i][j];
                            }
                            else if(j > k)
                            {
                                if (i == 1){
                                    placej = j-1;
                                }
                                temp_mat[placei][placej] = a[i][j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                res+=a[0][k]*determinant(temp_mat)*(int)Math.pow(-1, k);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    //Note: this method also works fine
    //Scalar product method
    public float[][] mul(float[][] m, float r)
    {
        float[][] res = new float[m.length][m.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
            {
                res[i][j]= m[i][j]*r;
            }
        }

        return res;

    }
    //Note: This method also works fine
    public float[][] mul(float[][] m,float[][] n)
    {
        float[][] res = new float[m.length][m.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < m.length; k++)
                {
                    res[i][j] += m[i][k]*m[k][i];
                }
            }
        }

        return res;

    }
    //The method for creating a matrix of minors
    //Here I start having problems
    public float[][] minor(float [][] m)
    {
        float [][] minor_mat = new float [m.length][m.length];
        //If the matrix is greater than a 2X2, use this to generate a matrix of minors
        if(m.length > 2)
        {
            float [][] current_minor = new float [m.length-1][m.length-1];
            int placei = 0;
            int placej = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < m.length; k++)
                    {
                        for(int l = 0; l < m.length; l++)
                        {
                            if(i != k && j != l)
                            {
                                if(k<i)
                                    placei = k;
                                else if(k>i)
                                    placei = k-1;
                                if(l<j)
                                    placej = l;
                                else if(l>j)
                                    placej = l-1;

                                current_minor[placei][placej] = m[k][l];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    minor_mat[i][j] = this.determinant(current_minor);
                }
            }
        }
        //otherwise use the definition for 2X2 matrix of minors
        else
        {
            //even though minor_mat is using m.clone() rather than m, when I return the result, m has still been modified for some reason.
            minor_mat = m.clone()
            float temp;
            temp = minor_mat[0][0];
            minor_mat[0][0] = minor_mat[1][1];
            minor_mat[1][1] = temp;
            temp = minor_mat[0][1];
            minor_mat[0][1] = minor_mat[1][0];
            minor_mat[1][0] = temp;
        }
        return minor_mat;
    }
    //the same problem occurs here as it did in the minor method
    //m appears to get modified even though I only use m.clone()
    public float[][] cofactor(float [][] m)
    {
        float[][] res = m.clone();
        res = this.minor(res)
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
            {
                res[i][j] = res[i][j]*(int)Math.pow(-1, i + j);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    //The following transpose, adjugate, and inverse methods have the same problem        

    public float[][] transpose(float[][] m)
    {
        float[][] res = new float[m.length][m.length];
        float temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++)
            {
                temp = m[i][j];
                res[i][j] = m[j][i];
                res[j][i] = temp;       
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public float[][] adjugate(float[][] m)
    {
        float[][] res = this.transpose(this.cofactor(m));
        return res;
    }
    public float[][] inverse(float[][] m)
    {
        float[][] res = this.mul(this.adjugate(m), (1/this.determinant(m)));
        return res;
    }
    //print out the matrix in square form
    public void matrixprint(float [][] m)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for(int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Now the main class and the main method that creates an instance of the MatrixOperations class and uses its methods on a 2X2 matrix.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixOperations mo = new MatrixOperations();

        //Create a 2X2 matrix called "matrix" and set its elements
        //Then perform each step on "matrix" and finally test if you have acquired the correct inverse

        float [][] matrix = new float[2][2];
        matrix[0][0] = 2;
        matrix [0][1] = 5;
        matrix [1][0] = 4;
        matrix [1][1] = 3;

        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Minor = ");
        mo.matrixprint(mo.minor(matrix));
        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Cofactor = ");
        mo.matrixprint(mo.cofactor(matrix));
        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Adjugate = ");
        mo.matrixprint(mo.adjugate(matrix));
        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Determinant = ");
        System.out.println(mo.determinant(matrix));
        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Inverse = ");
        mo.matrixprint(mo.inverse(matrix));
        System.out.println("Matrix = ");
        mo.matrixprint(matrix);
        System.out.println("Identity = ");
        mo.matrixprint(mo.mul(mo.inverse(matrix), matrix));

    }

}
```

Now you will see that when I show the output, every time I use a method on "matrix", and reprint "matrix", "matrix" itself has been modified even though my methods only use a copy of "matrix" and not "matrix" itself.

**Output:**

```
Matrix = 

2.0 5.0 
4.0 3.0 

Minor = 

3.0 4.0 
5.0 2.0 

Matrix = 

3.0 4.0 
5.0 2.0 

Cofactor = 

3.0 -4.0 
-5.0 2.0 

Matrix = 

3.0 -4.0 
-5.0 2.0 

Adjugate = 

3.0 5.0 
4.0 2.0 

Matrix = 

3.0 4.0 
5.0 2.0 

Determinant = 
-14.0
Matrix = 

3.0 4.0 
5.0 2.0 

Inverse = 

-0.21428573 0.35714287 
0.2857143 -0.14285715 

Matrix = 

3.0 -4.0 
-5.0 2.0 

Identity = 

0.1479592 0.1479592 
0.12244898 0.12244898
```

Any help/explanation as to why this happens would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line does a shallow clone;

```
float[][] res = m.clone();
```

This copies the `res` which is array fo references to arrays. but not any of the arrays `res` points to. Most likely what you wanted is

```
float[][] res = new float[m.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    res[i] = m[i].clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are passing reference of `matrix` object in the methods of `MatrixOperations` class. It's not a copy of `matrix` object.

From [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into
>   methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the
>   passed-in reference still references the same object as before.

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays. 
`clone()` on an array just does a shallow clone. 
So you have a new cloned outer array, but it references the same entries (the inner arrays). 
After cloning the outer array, iterate over the outer array and clone all inner arrays to get a deep clone.

Comment: If you are on Java 8, you can of course also use streams and lambdas to create your deep clone.